# Can the Upgrade: header have spaces between the comma?

Tags: http-headers

So, I see that Apache, by default shows the Upgrade header like this:

```
Upgrade: h2,h2c
```

Is this header below also valid?:

```
Upgrade: h2, h2c
```

Are spaces allowed between the commas in the Upgrade header?

### INFO:

### I talking about the response Upgrade: header which apache usually sends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably best answered by the RFC defining HTTP headers: [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

In section 4.2, defining the general form of headers, is written:

> Any LWS *[linear white space]*
> that occurs between field-content MAY be replaced with a single SP
> before interpreting the field value or forwarding the message
> downstream.

And the header format:

```
   message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
   field-name     = token
   field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
   field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                    and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                    of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

Note the section about field-content.
The section describing the upgrade header in special, 14.42, does not mention any further restrictions. This is why my answer to your question is:
Yes, space in between the values should be legal.

**[EDIT]**
Sorry about citing the wrong RFC, the correct one is [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) - but my answer is still valid, see [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#appendix-B). This section lists the changes from the obsolete RFC 2616, and a change of the header format is not listed.

The new definition, which is quite similiar, is found in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2), Secion 3.2:

```
 header-field   = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS

 field-name     = token
 field-value    = *( field-content / obs-fold )
 field-content  = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]
 field-vchar    = VCHAR / obs-text

 obs-fold       = CRLF 1*( SP / HTAB )
                ; obsolete line folding
                ; see Section 3.2.4
```

Comment: RFC 2616 is replaced by 7231

Comment: Are you sure it is still same?

Comment: you are right - hold on... let me edit my answer with the correct RFC, sorry about that!

Comment: So, the next time you answer questions, remind yourself to use 7231 :) (Unless of course it gets replaced with another new one) So, that your answer is valid.

Comment: Btw, I am talking about the response header.

Comment: I updated my answer, now it should be correct :)

Comment: the space is also allowed by the new RFC? Right?

Comment: yes. see the section about field-value, it has 1*SP / HTAB listed, which is space / horizontal tabulator.

Comment: LOL, I forgot to accept answer ...

Comment: Did you know it's possible to edit the answer instead of appending the corrections. ;)